# whats the issue with the below sql statements

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

i am trying to create a stored procedure but i dont know what the issue,SQLyog is continuously giving me errors

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE sim_management_update()
BEGIN
UPDATE bf_sim_management,test_sims SET 
bf_sim_management.`sim_company_id`=test_sims.`id` WHERE 
bf_sim_management.`sim_company_id`=test_sims.`display_name`
END //
DELIMITER;
```

The update statement alone is working fine and the error is

Query: CREATE PROCEDURE sim_management_update() BEGIN UPDATE bf_sim_management,test_sims SET bf_sim_management.`sim_company_id`=test_si...

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 4

Execution Time : 0 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0 sec

Comment: Missing `;` at the end of the update statement ?!

Comment: BTW: For a single-statement-procedure you don't need `BEGIN` and `END`, and thus you don't need to change the `DELIMITER`.

Comment: Please change the title to something like "MySQL PROCEDURE - error in your SQL syntax .. near 'END'". This might help other users with a similar problem to find this Q&A.

Comment: thankx alot @PaulSpiegel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should:

1. Put a semicolon at the end of your update statement.
2. Put a space between `DELIMITER` and `;`

Here's the example fixed:

```
DELIMITER //  
CREATE PROCEDURE sim_management_update()
  BEGIN
    UPDATE bf_sim_management,test_sims SET 
      bf_sim_management.`sim_company_id`=test_sims.`id` WHERE 
      bf_sim_management.`sim_company_id`=test_sims.`display_name`;
  END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

The code actually looks okay, but I would recommend writing it as:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE sim_management_update()
BEGIN
    UPDATE bf_sim_management sm JOIN
           test_sims ts
           ON sm.sim_company_id = ts.display_name
       SET sm.sim_company_id = ts.id;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Notes:

- The `SET` looks strange because I assume that `name` is a string and `id` is a number.  Usually, numbers are not assigned to strings.
- Use proper `JOIN` syntax.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- I added a semicolon at the end of the `update`.

Comment: "but I am not sure if that would cause your error" - It definitely does.

Comment: If you don't put a space between the `DELIMITER` and `;` the proc will get created but and error will be thrown and the delimiter will stay `//`